# Command to figure out how many threads are running for a given queue in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

I am exploring the sidekiq API and I am trying to find a way to check for a given queue, how many threads are running at a given moment ( I am using sidekiq limit fetch gem https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch , and I would like to be sure the limits I have set up in my config file are respected).
I had a look at `workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new` which is supposed to hold informations about threads but it doesnt show anything about the number of threads actually.
Is there a way to find out how many threads are running for a specific queue at a given moment in sidekiq ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested into [`Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#processes). From the docs:

> `Sidekiq::ProcessSet` gives you access to near real-time (updated every 5 sec) info about the current set of Sidekiq processes running. You can remotely control the processes also:

> ```
> ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new
> ```

```
ps.size # => 2
ps.each do |process|
  p process['busy']        # => 3
  p process['hostname']    # => 'myhost.local'
  p process['pid']         # => 16131
  p process['concurrency'] # => 10 <- this is the number of threads per process
end
```

Comment: I dont think so. ProcessSet only helps to check how many sidekiq processes you have currently running ie how many ```bundle exec sidekiq``` command you have running at a givent moment on your machine... What I am interested in is how many threads within this process I have at a given times working on one of my specific queue

Comment: I updated this answer to add the `concurrency`, which is the number of threads